# Get all value inside div element using ID

Tags: javascript, html, sightly

I think this is just a simple problem but I am stocked. I can't get all the value inside my div.

HTML Code

```
<div class="notice-items" id="notice-items">
   <div class="js-filter-item"
      data-filter-tags="${article.getTagValue}" >
         ${article.getTagValue}
   </div>
   <div class="js-filter-item"
      data-filter-tags="${article.getTagValue}" >
         ${article.getTagValue}
   </div>
   <div class="js-filter-item"
      data-filter-tags="${article.getTagValue}" >
         ${article.getTagValue}
   </div>
   <div class="js-filter-item"
      data-filter-tags="${article.getTagValue}" >
         ${article.getTagValue}
   </div>
</div>
```

Javascript Code

```
var $filterContainer = $("#".concat($('.js-tag-filters').data('container-id')));
var $filterItems = $filterContainer.find('.js-filter-item');
        
console.log("-- $filterContainer : " + JSON.stringify($filterContainer));
console.log("-- $filterItems : " + JSON.stringify($filterItems));
```

Out of all 4 values, only the first one is showing on my console.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFukc.png)

Thanks in advance for those who will help!

I've tried other javascript syntax but I can't still get the right output. Hope you could help.

Comment: I am guessing you are using jQuery, so you can try using a class selector instead, like so ``var allItems = $('.js-filter-item').attr('data-filter-tags')`` then you can loop through ``allItems`` since the data would be an array, like so ``allItems.forEach(function(item) { console.log(item) })``